# Applying multiple rotations in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have problems with the rotation of a game object. The game is in first person and the player can pick up physics objects from the ground. The object should keep its relative rotation to the camera. The game world is spherical so a rotation also has to be applied to match the player object's rotation when it is moving around the world carrying the object. There is also an ability to rotate the object around the Y axis using the keyboard.

```cs
Quaternion playerDeltaRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(originalPlayerForward, transform.forward);
closest.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, offsetRotation, 0) * originalItemRotation;
closest.transform.rotation = playerDeltaRotation * closest.transform.rotation;
```

The script is on the player GameObject.
closest is the object having been picked up.
playerDeltaRotation is the rotation that has been applied to the player object by the spherical world because the player has moved since picking up an object.
originalItemRotation is the rotation the object had when it was picked up.
offsetRotation is the Y axis rotation that can be manipulated using the keyboard.

The idea is to first apply the offsetRotation and then the playerDeltaRotation.
Is this a reasonable approach?

[This video shows the behaviour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pi2TYSuUNPY)

I get strange rotation that sometimes is around the wrong axis. Also, the object seems to make an extra full rotation when passing a certain point of the camera's rotation around the Y axis.

Comment: You might want to reconsider the design ... I personally would not move the player at all but rather place a anchor point to the middle of the sphere and then rotate it ... then the camera simply is a child of the player object and objects you pick up become children of the player object until you let go ... this way you wouldn't even have to think about relative rotation etc

Comment: @Flulff I agree with derHugo but what happens if you do `closest.transform.rotation = closest.transform.rotation * playerDeltaRotation;` instead of the other way around?

Comment: "Also, the object seems to make an extra full rotation when passing a certain point" I'm not sure if you're facing [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), which is sometimes caused by using EulerAngles instead of Quaternions. On another note, to what is the object in question parented?

Comment: @Fluff did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Comment: @Ruzihm Nope I did not